# How to Define Different Type of Users In Asp.Net MVC5 using EF Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I am Creating Clients Management System. using Asp.Net MVC5.
I Want to define multiple types of Users using Asp.Net Identity 2.x
Ex: 
Client , Employee , Affiliates 
these are not roles because they all have different properties some of them are same.
and for authentication i want to use Identity User as Identity will take care for rest of work in term of authorisation and authentication.
now i want to know how to define relationship between them.

i have tried some codes, but i don't know if its very good in a way to run this project on Live Server.

### IdentityUser Class

"Identity User Creates default properties for user."

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<string, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, AppUserClaim>, IUser<string>
    {
        public AppUser()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
            GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<AppUser, string> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager
                .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }        
    }
```

### Client Class

```
public class Client
    {      

        public string AppUserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AppUserId")]
        public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }

        public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
        public virtual Employee Employee{ get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> DOB { get; set; }

    }
```

### Employee Class

```
public class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> DOB { get; set; }

        public IList<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        public string AppUserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AppUserId")]
        public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public IList<string> UserRoles{ get; set; }

    }
```

### Affiliate Class

```
public class Affiliate
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public decimal Commission { get; set; }
        public string AppUserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AppUserId")]
        public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }

    }
```

Now These are my User Types and their Relationships,

when i create any user,

for Ex:

```
var client = new client();
client.FirstName = "abc";
client.LastName = "xyz";
client.AppUser.Email = "abc@example.com";
client.AppUser.UserName = "abc@example.com";
client.AppUser.Password= "123456";

var db = new myContext();
db.client.add(client);
```

It also works fine.

the problem is when i update the record 
so i have to update both entities , 
i cant update both entities at once,
i have to update AppUser 1st then Client/Employee
OR Client/Employee and then AppUser.

i don't know how to write a better code to update both entities successfully
because i can't update 
for Ex:

```
public JsonResult Update(Client cm)
{
var db = new myContext();
//var client = db.clients.where(x=>x.Id == cm.Id).firstordefault();
var client = db.clients.find(cm.Id);

client.FirstName = cm.FirstName;
client.LastName = cm.LastName ;
client.AppUser.Email = cm.Email;
client.AppUser.UserName = cm.Email;
client.AppUser.Password= cm.Password;


db.Entry(client).State =  System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
return Context.SaveChanges() > 0;

}
```

it throws error

An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker. On multiple entries

I tried to update both entities separately,

For Ex:

to update AppUser 
I Used UserManager

```
public JsonResult Update(Client cm)
{

var db = new myContext();
//var client = db.clients.where(x=>x.Id == cm.Id).firstordefault();
var client = db.clients.find(cm.Id);
var appUser = UserManager.Find(cm.AppUserId);

client.FirstName = cm.FirstName;
client.LastName = cm.LastName ;

appUser.Id = cm.AppUserId;
appUser.Email = cm.Email;
appUser.UserName = cm.Email;
appUser.Password= cm.Password;

 UserManager.Update(appUser);

db.Entry(client).State =    System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
 Context.SaveChanges();

}
```

here is the point i wanna know if appUser updated successfully 
and then got error while updating client 
how to retrieve appuser previous record.

How to do it with good practise .. Sorry if i couldn't make it easy to understand.

How To define the relation between IdentityUser and Employee/Client/Affiliates